# Toggle class between 3 elements using Angular6

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

I have three div's

```
<div class = "form">
 <div class = "group"></div>
 <div class = "group"></div>
 <div class = "group"></div>
</div>
```

Now, i want to add class 'active' with 'group' class on click. By default it should be present on the first 'group' class div. 'active' class can only be present at one div at a time

`.ts` file:

```
selectStatus: boolean = false;

selectGroup() {
  this.selectStatus = !this.selectStatus;
}
```

`.html` file:

```
<div class = "form">
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
</div>
```

But it's adding the `active` class on all the `div`s

```
<div class = "form">
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup()" [ngClass]="{selectStatus ? 'active' : 'not-active'}"></div>
</div>

selectStatus: boolean = false;

selectGroup() {
  this.selectStatus = !this.selectStatus;
}
```

It coming on all div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ts` file:

```
activeDivIndex: number = 0;

selectGroup(activeDivIndex: number) {
  this.activeDivIndex= activeDivIndex;
}
```

View:

```
<div class = "form">
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(0)" [ngClass]="activeDivIndex == 0? 'active' : 'not-active'"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(1)" [ngClass]="activeDivIndex == 1? 'active' : 'not-active'"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(2)" [ngClass]="activeDivIndex == 2? 'active' : 'not-active'"></div>
</div>
```

Better yet, you could use an `ngFor` and check if the current index is the same as `activeDivIndex`

`.ts` file:

```
groupList: Array<Object> = [{foo: "Foo 1", bar: "Bar 1"}, {foo: "Foo 2", bar: "Bar 2"}, {foo: "Foo 3", bar: "Bar 3"}];
activeDivIndex: number = 0;


selectGroup(activeDivIndex: number) {
  this.activeDivIndex= activeDivIndex;
}
```

View:

```
<div class = "form">
  <div *ngFor="let groupItem of groupList, let i = index" class="group" (click)="selectGroup(i)" [ngClass]="activeDivIndex === i ? 'active' : 'not-active'">Foo: {{groupItem.foo}}, Bar: {{groupItem.bar}}</div>
</div>
```

or if you don't need the `not-active` class:

```
<div class = "form">
  <div *ngFor="let groupItem of groupList, let i = index" class="group" (click)="selectGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{'active': activeDivIndex === i}">Foo: {{groupItem.foo}}, Bar: {{groupItem.bar}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't understtod sorry!
i have activeDivIndex variable then in the click function how to iterate?

Comment: @juhi Updated the answer, is this better?

Comment: @juhi Did you try either of those 2 ways?

Comment: i am trying the one with *ngFor, but i have multiple different texts in these three groups

Comment: @juhi You can use an `Array<Object>` instead of `Array<string>` and print the part you want wherever you want. (see updated answer). You could also use a different view if it's too complicated.

Comment: @juhi Glad I could help, you can also up-vote all the answers that helped you (mine and/or user's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code as follows:

.html

```
<div class = "form">
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(0)" [ngClass]="{'active': selectStatus[0]}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(1)" [ngClass]="{'active': selectStatus[1]}"></div>
  <div class = "group" (click) = "selectGroup(2)" [ngClass]="{'active': selectStatus[2]}"></div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
selectStatus = [true, false, false];

selectGroup(id) {
    this.selectStatus = this.selectStatus.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === id) {
             return true;
        } 
        return false;            
    })
}
```

Working sample is given here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mebcte)

Comment: item = true; / item = false;
not able to access it within if function
so it's not workng

Comment: @user could just do `(item, index) => index === id`

Comment: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
i am getting this error, though it is working fine